# Move string on the Image using Trackbar

Tags: c#, graphics, picturebox

I want to move a string after scrolling Trackbar. Problem is, the previous string stays with the new one. So the resultant `Image` gets an unreadable string.

```
Image img;
readonly Image _originalImg;
Graphics imgScale;

public Form(){
    InitializeComponent();
    _originalImg = Image.FromFile("d:\\a.jpg");
    img = _originalImg;
    imgScale = Graphics.FromImage(img);
}

private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    img = null;
    pictureBox1.Image = null;
    imgScale = null;

    img = _originalImg;

    x = trackBar1.Value;
    imgScale = Graphics.FromImage(img);
    imgScale.DrawString(str, font, color, new PointF(x, 0));
    pictureBox1.Image = img;
}
```

Can anybody please edit my code so that `_originalImg` stays as new and I can see a clear string on the Image.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
readonly Image _originalImg;

public Form(){

    InitializeComponent();
    _originalImg = Image.FromFile("d:\\a.jpg");
}

private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}

private void pictureBox1_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(_originalImg, 0, 0);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(str, font, color, new PointF( trackBar1.Value, 0));
}
```

Roughly what we are doing here, is drawing your image onto the picturebox, and also drawing the text onto the picturebox.  This means the original image will never get modified.

We also only update the image if something changes (or the form gets told to repaint by windows etc).  To ensure the image updates, we call `pictureBox1.Invalidate();` when the trackbar value changes.

### Edit:

---

As you don't want to save the image with the text else where, we can simplify this greatly:

```
public Form(){

    InitializeComponent();
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("d:\\a.jpg");
    pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
}

private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}

private void pictureBox1_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(str, font, color, new PointF( trackBar1.Value, 0));
}
```

This will draw the image zoomed onto the picturebox, and then over the top of that, we draw the text.  This means the image is zoomed, but the text remains at whatever font size you specify.

Comment: But I need to draw the String every time I scroll te trackbar. This just show me the string. How to draw the string on the image every time?

Comment: @whoone: not quite sure I follow you - this will draw the string on top of the image in the picturebox.  Are you also after a separate image object, which has the string also on it?

Comment: I need a while. I'll answer you.

Comment: Sorry for incorrect info, the string is ok with your code. Now the the problem is the image do not set in the Picturebox as zoom. I mean I need to set size mode property to zoom. I tried this "pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;" but didn't work.

Comment: As _pictureBox1 shows error I used pictureBox1 instead. Still the picture do not get zoom as size mode